# Mysql to eloquent (where multiples row equals a value)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I wish to build a new website based on my old website. To do that i use Laravel 4 (I cannot use Laravel 5 because of the limitations of my hosting).

I have a problem on a MYSQL query that I want to transform into a Laravel Eloquent query.

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_sondage WHERE sondage_home='1' AND (sondage_v1+sondage_v2+sondage_v3+sondage_v4+sondage_v5+sondage_v6+sondage_v7+sondage_v8+sondage_v9+sondage_v10) >= 40 ORDER BY RAND()"
```

Have you an idea of how I can transform this MYSQL Query into Laravel Eloquent Query?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Explain, please, what did you tried to do and where you stuck? I don't see any problems with this if you read the documentation.

Comment: @rMX I add (calculate) the result all the fields to verify them with a value (> 40) but I do not succeed in making Eloquent Query with that. How do you make?

Comment: You *must* show at least an attempt you made, so that we are able to figure out where your problem is. As it stands, there is little to say but "read the, hum, [manual](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage)"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DB::table('tbl_sondage')->select(DB::raw('tbl_sondage.*,(sondage_v1+sondage_v2+sondage_v3+sondage_v4+sondage_v5+sondage_v6+sondage_v7+sondage_v8+sondage_v9+sondage_v10) AS sumofsondage'))->where('sondage_home', 1)->orWhere('sumofsondage', '>=', 40)->orderByRaw("RAND()")->get();
```

*Not tested*